# How to use firebase reset password in React-Redux login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to include a reset password functionality using firebase in my react-redux login page, however I seem a bit lost.

I included the code below in my userActions.js and also installed firebase on the client-side.

```
export const resetPassword = email => async dispatch => {
  try {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
      .then(() =>
        dispatch({
          type: RESET_SUCCESS,
          payload: "Reset email sent. Go check your inbox."
        })
      )
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({
          type: RESET_ERROR,
          payload: "...some message for the user..."
        });
      });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_ERROR,
      payload: "...some message for the user..."
    });
  }
};
```

In my types.js, I included this as well

```
export const RESET_SUCCESS = "RESET_SUCCESS";
export const RESET_ERROR = "RESET_ERROR";
```

I've imported the resetPassword in my login page as well

```
import { resetPassword } from "../redux/actions/userActions";
```

My question is that... how can I add the resetPassword I imported to a button called 'Reset Password'? N/B: I used the handleSubmit for user login functionality. I'm also using form from Material UI for my login functionality. I'm a react newbie, I'd really appreciate if someone puts me through

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `resetPassword` function works correctly. You can use it in your react component like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Buttton } from 'material-ui';
import { resetPassword } from '../redux/actions/userActions';

class Example extends Component {
  state = { loading: false };
  handleReset = async () => {
    const { email, dispatch } = this.props;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    await resetPassword(email)(dispatch);
    // message or alert you want to display
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Buttton loading={this.state.loading} onClick={this.handleReset}>
        Reset Password
      </Buttton>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Example);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got an error message -> Dispatch is not a function